# Sometimes getting error Insufficient funs for gas * price + value?

Tags: transactions, ether

I use Goerli testnet and I make the transaction compatible with **EIP1559**. I also use from [etherscan gastracker api](https://etherscan.io/gastracker) for getting desired low, average, and high values for maxFeePerGas.
Issue is **sometimes** transaction does not send and goerli.infura give error "insufficient funs for gas * price + value", but when I increase maxFeePerGas value, transaction will send successfully.

**Notice that I use **etherescan mainnet gasTracker** for maxFeePerGas not goerli gasTracker. Does need to goerli gastracker? Is that possible, this issue doesn't occur on mainnet?

Comment: You should provide more details about a transaction that gives that error, like gas, value, maxFeePerGas and sender balance at the time. It could be a simple error as  using a wrong unit for some of them, or using an incorrect value for them.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error is saying: Within your account holding the Goerli Ether you should have a minimum of maxFeePerGas * gas + value. If you don't have this your transaction should be rejected by the libraries. Maybe try to switch to a more accurate provider like Alchemy or Infura. Lower latency helps getting better and faster results for queries.

Comment: Thanks. But I sure that I have minumum maxFeePerGas * gas + value on my account. I use infura too. Same transaction, first time getting error, but second time it is done without error.